# Can't read mouse event use ReadConsoleInput in C++

Tags: c++, console, mouse

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

HANDLE hStdin;
DWORD fdwSaveOldMode;

VOID ErrorExit(LPSTR);
VOID KeyEventProc(KEY_EVENT_RECORD);
VOID MouseEventProc(MOUSE_EVENT_RECORD);
VOID ResizeEventProc(WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_RECORD);

int main(VOID)
{
    DWORD cNumRead, fdwMode, i;
    INPUT_RECORD irInBuf[128];
    int counter = 0;

    // Get the standard input handle. 

    hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    if (hStdin == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        ErrorExit("GetStdHandle");

    // Save the current input mode, to be restored on exit. 

    if (!GetConsoleMode(hStdin, &fdwSaveOldMode))
        ErrorExit("GetConsoleMode");

    // Enable the window and mouse input events. 

    fdwMode = ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT | ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT;
    if (!SetConsoleMode(hStdin, fdwMode))
        ErrorExit("SetConsoleMode");

    // Loop to read and handle the next 100 input events. 

    while (counter++ <= 1000)
    {
        // Wait for the events. 

        if (!ReadConsoleInput(
            hStdin,      // input buffer handle 
            irInBuf,     // buffer to read into 
            128,         // size of read buffer 
            &cNumRead)) // number of records read 
            ErrorExit("ReadConsoleInput");

        // Dispatch the events to the appropriate handler. 
        for (i = 0; i < cNumRead; i++)
        {
            printf("inlnBuf.EventType : %d ", irInBuf[i].EventType);
            switch (irInBuf[i].EventType)
            {
            case KEY_EVENT: // keyboard input 
                KeyEventProc(irInBuf[i].Event.KeyEvent);
                break;

            case MOUSE_EVENT: // mouse input 
                MouseEventProc(irInBuf[i].Event.MouseEvent);
                break;

            case WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_EVENT: // scrn buf. resizing 
                ResizeEventProc(irInBuf[i].Event.WindowBufferSizeEvent);
                break;

            case FOCUS_EVENT:  // disregard focus events 

            case MENU_EVENT:   // disregard menu events 
                break;

            default:
                ErrorExit("Unknown event type");
                break;
            }
            puts("");
        }
    }

    // Restore input mode on exit.

    SetConsoleMode(hStdin, fdwSaveOldMode);

    return 0;
}

VOID ErrorExit(LPSTR lpszMessage)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", lpszMessage);

    // Restore input mode on exit.

    SetConsoleMode(hStdin, fdwSaveOldMode);

    ExitProcess(0);
}

VOID KeyEventProc(KEY_EVENT_RECORD ker)
{
    printf("Key event: ");

    if (ker.bKeyDown)
        printf("key pressed\n");
    else printf("key released\n");
}

VOID MouseEventProc(MOUSE_EVENT_RECORD mer)
{
#ifndef MOUSE_HWHEELED
#define MOUSE_HWHEELED 0x0008
#endif
    printf("Mouse event: ");

    switch (mer.dwEventFlags)
    {
    case 0:

        if (mer.dwButtonState == FROM_LEFT_1ST_BUTTON_PRESSED)
        {
            printf("left button press \n");
        }
        else if (mer.dwButtonState == RIGHTMOST_BUTTON_PRESSED)
        {
            printf("right button press \n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("button press\n");
        }
        break;
    case DOUBLE_CLICK:
        printf("double click\n");
        break;
    case MOUSE_HWHEELED:
        printf("horizontal mouse wheel\n");
        break;
    case MOUSE_MOVED:
        printf("mouse moved\n");
        break;
    case MOUSE_WHEELED:
        printf("vertical mouse wheel\n");
        break;
    default:
        printf("unknown\n");
        break;
    }
}

VOID ResizeEventProc(WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_RECORD wbsr)
{
    printf("Resize event\n");
    printf("Console screen buffer is %d columns by %d rows.\n", wbsr.dwSize.X, wbsr.dwSize.Y);
}
```

[image]

I use msdn example ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/eu-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685035(v=vs.85).aspx )

And I checked correct action on other computer 
but on my computer, I can only read keyboard input.

How can I read mouse event?

I use Windows 10 64-bit, VS 2015.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works when I change the following line to:

```
fdwMode = ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS | ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT | ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT;
```

According to the documentation for ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS:

> Required to enable or disable extended flags. See ENABLE_INSERT_MODE and ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE.

It makes no mention of the effect on ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT.